# Why i can not get current_user while writing test case with Rspec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, integration-testing, capybara

I have to write integration test case for my one feature listing page and that feature index method has code like below

```
def index
  @food_categories = current_user.food_categories
end
```

Now when i try to write a test case for this it throws an error

```
'undefined method features for nil class' because it can not get the current user
```

Now what i have do is below
I have write the login process in the before each statement and then write the test case for the features listing page

Can you please let me know that how i can get the `current_user` ?

FYI, I have used devise gem and working on integration test case with Rspec

Here is [my spec file](https://gist.github.com/2319172)
And here is my [food_categories_spec.rb](https://gist.github.com/2319177)

Comment: Hey @chirag.sweng you may want to swap around the names for the links you provided. The spec_helper file points to the foot_categories_spec file and vice versa. Just a note really.
    Here is my spec file And here is my food_categories_spec.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: you confuse functional and integration tests. Integration test doesn't use `get`, because there's no controller action to test, instead you must use `visit` (some url). Then you have to examine content of a page, not response code (latter is for functional tests). It may look like:

```
visit '/food_categories'
page.should have_content 'Eggs'
page.should have_content 'Fats and oils'
```

In case you'll need *functional* test, here's an example:

```
# spec/controllers/your_controller_spec.rb
describe YourController do

  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "GET index" do

    before do
      get :index
    end

    it "is successful" do
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "assings user features" do
      assigns(:features).should == @user.features
    end
  end
end

# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  #...
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it throws error undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xa95fa38>, please let me know if you have any idea

Comment: FYI i am writing integration test case

Comment: Yeah, thanks for quick reply but i have already added that in my spec_helper.rb, do you want me to show you my spec_helper.rb file ?

Comment: @chirag.sweng `spec_helper` and spec you have problem with would be a minimum. Always provide in question as much information as you can.

Comment: @chirag.sweng I missed your remark about integration test (you *should* note about that in question!). Are you sure you need integration test? Assigns are tested only in functional tests (`spec/controllers`). Integrational tests are made in order to be sure that specific links, buttons and other HTML elements are on a page, and you can interact with them.

Comment: Yes, i am using capybara for integration test and i have added test case for the sign in, but after that i want to go on the features page where i have current_user.features but this does not work

Comment: @chirag.sweng still waiting for your problem spec

Comment: here it is [spec](https://gist.github.com/2319172) and here spec_helper [spec_helper](https://gist.github.com/2319177)

Comment: @chirag.sweng so, where's your *failing* example? update your answer, if you want to get any help (nobody reads comments, seriously)

Comment: see line 24 on spec.. get food_categories_path where i have same current_user.food_categories in my food_categories controller @Nash.. I will update my question now.. thanks