# Rspec/Rails 4, access current_user from Rspec.feature spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

I'm able to access current_user from controller specs no problem. From within an Rspec.feature spec, I'm having trouble making current_user available.

The reason I need a current_user is, I am testing a Send Invitation feature. I navigate to the page from which invitations are sent, fill in the invite[to_user] field, and click 'Send Invitation'. I want to make sure that the proper flash message is being display on the page. However, I am setting the sender_id to current_user id in the controller action that is triggered by clicking on 'Send Invitation' - here is where I need current_user to be defined.

I set up support/controller_macros.rb for controller tests like so:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

support/devise.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
    config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

login_user is not available inside of the Rspec.feature spec...which makes sense, becasue the type is 'feature' not 'controller'. I'm assuming that is the reason why.

I figured I should be able to call sign_in from with the Rspec.feature spec. But that doesn't work...the sign_in method isn't available either. Here is the spec I am trying to get working:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Carpool Invitations", :type => :feature do
    let!(:carpool) { FactoryGirl.create(:carpool)}
    let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user)}


  scenario "User sends a new carpool invite" do
        sign_in user

    visit new_carpool_invite_path(carpool)
    fill_in "invite[to_user]", :with => "matthewalexander108@gmail.com"
    click_button "Send Invitation"
    expect(page).to have_text("Invitation was successfully sent!")
  end
end
```

Is there a way to configure Rspec.feature specs so it can see, and use, the login_user method define in the support/controller_macros.rb file? I've looked at:

[Why i can not get current_user while writing test case with Rspec and Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039253/why-i-can-not-get-current-user-while-writing-test-case-with-rspec-and-capybara)

but I wasn't able to get what I need.

UPDATE:

My question is different because I am running an integration test, ultimately I am testing the content of page. The integration test I am running involves sending an invite, the sending invite action creates an invite object, in the process of creating an invite,  current_user.id is added as the `sender_id` of the invite object being created. Once the invite is successfully created, the same page reloads with a flash message.

I am testing the flash message.

In order to do this, I need current_user to be defined in the action that creates the invite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why i can not get current\_user while writing test case with Rspec and Capybara](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039253/why-i-can-not-get-current-user-while-writing-test-case-with-rspec-and-capybara)

Comment: why not create your own module helper e.g `module FeatureHelper` like the `module ControllerMacros` specifically for feature test.

Comment: The first part of the accepted answer to the question you cited is the answer you're looking for. Don't try to check `current_user` in a feature spec; check the page to see who's logged in.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth, what I was looking is in the second part of rmhunters answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

Don't use controller helpers in feature specs -- in BDD, you want the feature specs to do everything through the browser DSL (like Capybara). In your case, it would be better to write a separate helper method for signing in with Capybara (example below).

---

### Explanation

You want your feature spec to be from the perspective of the user. The user doesn't care how the controller creates a user session, and neither should your feature spec. It should stay within the domain of the spec type.

In your case, the better solution would be to write a another helper method (specifically for `:feature` specs) that signs the user in through Capybara methods, so that your entire feature test occurs from the same flow/perspective. Here's a generic helper method that I use in all my apps:

```
# spec/support/feature_helpers.rb
module FeatureHelpers
  def sign_in
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit "/"
    click_link "Sign In"
    fill_in "user_email", with: @user.email
    fill_in "user_password", with: @user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FeatureHelpers, :type => :feature
end
```

Then, your spec would look something like this:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Carpool Invitations", :type => :feature do
  let!(:carpool) { FactoryGirl.create(:carpool)}
  # you could still create a user here if you wanted

  scenario "User sends a new carpool invite" do
    sign_in
    visit new_carpool_invite_path(carpool)
    fill_in "invite[to_user]", :with => "matthewalexander108@gmail.com"
    click_button "Send Invitation"
    expect(page).to have_text("Invitation was successfully sent!")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Worked great.

Comment: You're welcome! Hopefully you used the "better" solution...I'm actually editing my answer to remove the dirty solution because it isn't even guaranteed to work.

Comment: I did use the 'better solution'

Comment: The quick and dirty solution behaved a little weird ;) I would definitely remove it

Comment: Yeah it was vulnerable to side effects, I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

your rails_helper.rb has this?

`Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }`

only for testing add this config in your `rails_helper.rb`

```
require 'devise'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  #...
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  #... 
end
```